# Replacing last n rows of a column in a dataframe with values from a column in a smaller dataframe

Tags: r

Lets say I have 2 separate data frames, one with 10 rows of data, and one with 5 rows of data. Let's say I want to replace the last 5 rows of data in a specific column of dataframe 1 with the values in a specific column of data frame 2. How would I go about doing this?

For simplicity, let's say there are two dataframes of just 1 column in this example

```
vect1<- c(1:10)
vect2<- c(11:15)

as.data.frame(vect1)
as.data.frame(vect2)
```

How would I go about replacing the last 5 values in vector 1 with the 5 values in vector 2? So the output would be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work for you?

```
> vect1_df <- data.frame(vect1)
> vect2_df <- data.frame(vect2)
> vect1_df$vect1[6:10] <- vect2_df$vect2
> vect1_df
   vect1
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
6     11
7     12
8     13
9     14
10    15
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `replace` while specifying the row index with `tail` to replace those elements with the second vector

```
vec1new <- replace(vect1, tail(seq_along(vect1), 5), vect2)
vec1new
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5 11 12 13 14 15
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vect1<- c(1:10)
vect2<- c(11:15)


vect1[6:10] = vect2
```

This would make vect1's last 5 digit be replaced with vect2

```
> vect1
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5 11 12 13 14 15
```